# Convert a SVN repo to a HG repo and discard revision comments

Tags: svn, mercurial

I want to create a HG repository from a SVN repository, but I do not want the HG repository to have any of the commit comments. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: seams that you just want a plain new HG repository, right? You can create an HG repository right on top of an SVN one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I mean I want to convert a SVN to a HG repo with all of the individual commits, just not their comments.

Comment: I can't imagine why this could ever be useful. surely some comment, no matter how bad, is better than no comment

Answer (score 1):

Import svn repository with comments (eiher via Convert extension or hgsubversion bridge). Than use [HistEdit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) to rewrite history and remove comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind editing a bit of Python code, get a local hg installation and change its convert extension to clobber all commit messages during conversion.

Something like

```
diff --git a/hgext/convert/convcmd.py b/hgext/convert/convcmd.py
--- a/hgext/convert/convcmd.py
+++ b/hgext/convert/convcmd.py
@@ -294,6 +294,7 @@
         commit.author = self.authors.get(commit.author, commit.author)
         commit.branch = self.branchmap.get(commit.branch, commit.branch)
         self.commitcache[rev] = commit
+        commit.desc = 'no message'
         return commit

     def copy(self, rev):
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

- Update your SVN folder on disk, then wipe out
  all the '.svn' subfolders. Or, with
  TortoiseSVN Repository Explorer, navigate to the desired
  folder and export it to your disk.
- Add the files to a fresh HG repository.

HTH
Thomas

Comment: That would take a lot of manual exports/imports to get every revision.

Comment: So you want to keep the revisions and only get rid of the associated comments?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the revisions and only get rid of the associated comments.

Comment: Hmm, AFAIK there's no simple way. Even if you use the HistEdit HG-extension from below you have to edit each and every single changeset...
But I'm curious: Why do you want to do that?